# Please check whether my solution is correct? Directional derivative?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Question says....
Let $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be differentiable.
At $(1,2)$ $f$ has directional derivative $2$ in the direction towards $(2,2)$ and $-2$ in the direction towards $(1,-1)$.
find grad $f$ at $(1,2)$.
directional derivative towards $(4,6)$.
Solution: direction vector from $(1,2)$ to $(2,2)$ is $(1,0)$.
          direction vector from $(1,2)$ to $(1,-1)$ is $(0,-3)$.
          direction vector from $(1,2)$ to $(4,6)$ is $(3,4)$.
         $ u=(3/5 , 4/5)$.
D.D $f(1,2)=\mathrm{grad}\, f(1,2)u=(1/5)[\mathrm{grad}\, f(1,2)(3,4)]
                       =(1/5)[3 \mathrm{grad}\, f(1,2)(1,0) -4/3 \mathrm{grad}\, f(1,2)(0,-3)]=(1/5)[3*2-4/3*-2]=52/5$.
Is it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient of $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ at $(1,2)$ is a two-dimensional vector, so let's assume that it is $(a,b)$.

We have the following fact: the directional derivative of $f$ towards $(c,d)$ at $(1,2)$ is equal to the dot product of the gradient and  $(c,d)$, that is
$$(a,b)\cdot (c,d)=ac+bd.$$
Hence, by assumption, the directional derivative of $f$  towards $(2,2)$ is
$$\tag{1}2=(a,b)\cdot (2,2)=2a+2b,$$
and the directional derivative of $f$  towards $(1,-1)$ is
$$\tag{2}-2=(a,b)\cdot (1,-1)=a-b.$$
Now, solving $(1)$ and $(2)$, we can find $a$ and $b$, and as a result the gradient of $f$ at $(1,2)$.

On the other hand, the directional derivative of $f$ towards $(4,6)$ at $(1,2)$ is given by 
$$(a,b)\cdot (4,6)=4a+6b.$$
Hope that it helps.

Comment: given answer is 2i+2j and 14/5

Comment: after finding a and b where should I substitute them?

Comment: Thank you any way ... I have solved it and found the answers.